# Is there a difference between these two queries?

Tags: mysql

Well, pretty simple question I think, but I can't find a satisfying answer.
Is there a difference between these two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 = 'x' OR column2 = 'x'

SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column1 = 'x' OR column2 = 'x')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: There is not, but you should get used to put OR condition in parentheses because AND has higher priority than OR -> `x and (y or z)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is **NO** difference in your queries.

There would be difference if there would be `AND` condition as addition in your query.

e.g

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND column1 = 'x' OR column2 = 'x'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND (column1 = 'x' OR column2 = 'x')
```

#### Note

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1 AND column1 = 'x' OR column2 = 'x'
```

would be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id=1 AND column1 = 'x') OR column2 = 'x'
```

### Hope you get the difference.

Answer (score 3):

The role of parenthesis will be usefull when there is one more condition with AND operator.
otherwise no difference in execution plan except syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment above, [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/where-optimizations.html) explains:

> Some of the optimizations performed by MySQL follow:
>
> - Removal of unnecessary parentheses:
>
>   ```
>      ((a AND b) AND c OR (((a AND b) AND (c AND d))))
>   -> (a AND b AND c) OR (a AND b AND c AND d)
>   ```

So no, there is no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not a single difference.

See more MySQL Syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html).

Answer (score 1):

No. its the same. As long as there are only two conditions braces doesn't have much significance.