# LIKE function in mysql with different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys I am having issue

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM useraccount
WHERE
  (FirstName LIKE '%a%') OR
  (LastName LIKE '%a%') AND
  (Company = '131') AND
  (Type = '4') 
GROUP BY ID
```

but it is not functioning as I want. For example LIKE function should be like this. But must be 131 and type 4. it is not taking this two features.

Comment: If you think RenePot answer is CORRECT answer, please ***[accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)***, This is how SO works... ***Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815979/1066828)***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to add some extra parentheses around the `OR` part:

```
WHERE ((FirstName LIKE '%a%') OR (LastName LIKE '%a%')) AND ...
```

This is because `AND` have higher precedence (i.e., will be evaluated before) `OR`. You can read more about this at the [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html) page in the manual.

Comment: Thank you, I got it worked, I could not figure out. Appreciate

Comment: @Akram : If you think this is answer, please ***[accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)***, This is how SO works... ***Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10815979/1066828)***

Comment: actually he just need one parenthesis to wrap the OR