# MySQL Select users where first and second names like x and x

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't think of a way to word the title, so sorry for that, basically I have a search function on my site, it's supposed to select users from the database where the query entered is either like their first, second, first and second, or is their first and second, first, or second name. (That confused the hell out of me to type)

The code:

```
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags(stripslashes(@$_GET['q']))));
    $searchArray = explode(" ", $query);
    $query = trim($query);

if($query == "" || $searchArray == "") {
                    echo("<div id='result'><p>Please enter a search term</p></div>");
                }
                if (!isset($query) || !isset($searchArray)){
                    echo("<div id='result'><p>Please enter a search term</p></div>");
                }
                if (count($searchArray) > 1) {
                    $sq = mysql_query("
                    SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
                    OR fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
                    OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
                    OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
                    OR fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' AND sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
                    OR fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' AND sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%'
                    OR fname = '%{$searchArray[0]}%' AND sname = '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
                    OR fname = '%{$searchArray[1]}%' AND sname = '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
                    ");
                } 

                else{
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname AND sname LIKE '%$query%' OR email LIKE '%$query%'";
                }
```

In my database I have the following users:
Declan Smith
Joseph Brailsford
Test User
Test User 2

If I search for e-mails, I get the right result.
If I search for Dec, Declan, or Smith, I get the right result.
If I search for Test, Test User or User, I get no result.
If I search for Joseph, Brailsford or Joseph Brailsford, I get no result.
If I search for Declan Smith, I get Joseph Brailsford as the result.

Obviously, that isn't right, at all, so could someone please tell me what I've done wrong?:/

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname AND sname LIKE '%$query%' OR email LIKE '%$query%'";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE 
             fname LIKE '%$query%' OR
             sname LIKE '%$query%' OR 
             email LIKE '%$query%'";
```

OR

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(fname, ', ', sname, ', ', email) LIKE '%$query%'";
```

so that you don't have to write those OR conditions...

Also your first query should be

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE concat(fname, ', ', sname) LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
OR concat(fname, ', ', sname) LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%'
```

Also read ***[Is there a difference between these two queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10815979/1066828)***

Comment: I still have a problem, if I enter "Name Surname" it only returns Joseph Brailsford as the result, no matter what is put in.

Comment: If it's the $sq that runs, i.e, the get id s?=name+name, the $sq= Resource id #8. The $sql is correct and works. It's that first one that doesn't.

Comment: then can you `echo $sq` and let me know what query you get?

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE concat(fname, ', ', sname) LIKE '%Declan%' OR concat(fname, ', ', sname) LIKE '%Smith%'

Comment: Accepted for all the help + most complete answer. My problem was that I had $sq = mysql_query("stuff"); not, $sql = "stuff", mysql_query($sq)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure of the logic as you've written it, but I think only these are necessary:

```
SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
     OR fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
     OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
     OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%'
```

All the other parts of that WHERE clause seem redundant.  But if you do really need them, I think you want parentheses.  Otherwise the "AND" breaks any hope of it working:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
     OR fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
     OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' 
     OR sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' 
     OR (fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%' AND sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%')
     OR (fname LIKE '%{$searchArray[1]}%' AND sname LIKE '%{$searchArray[0]}%')
     OR (fname = '%{$searchArray[0]}%' AND sname = '%{$searchArray[1]}%')
     OR (fname = '%{$searchArray[1]}%' AND sname = '%{$searchArray[0]}%')
```

And those last two lines... Why the % with equals tests?  Certainly you don't need those.

Comment: The problem I have now is that if I search for "Name Surname" I'm only getting Joseph Brailsford for the result, no matter what.